# Use of two pairs of brackets in Angular2 expression template syntax

Tags: angular

I see the following in the app.component.ts file in John Papa's 'Tour of Heroes' sample app:

```
<a [router-link]="[routes.dashboard]">Dashboard</a>
<a [router-link]="[routes.heroes]">Heroes</a>
```

I understand the use of the brackets on the left-hand side of the equal sign (binding), but do not understand the use of the brackets on the right-hand side.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Read the [RouterLink](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouterLink-directive.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are for defining an array.
Extract from [RouterLink documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouterLink-directive.html):

> RouterLink expects the value to be an array of route names, followed by the params for that level of routing. For instance **['/Team', {teamId: 1}, 'User', {userId: 2}]** means that we want to generate a link for the Team route with params **{teamId: 1}**, and with a child route User with params **{userId: 2}**.

Comment: There is a router link syntax that this represents. Keep an eye on this as it may get some sugar syntax to make it easier